# Add a Top Single Row to the Ordered result Set of a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a very simple requirement.

```
SELECT NULL as ProjectId, 'All' as ProjectName

UNION

(
  SELECT  Project.ProjectId,  Project.ProjectName
  FROM Project Order by 2
)
```

Original order of  entries:

```
ProjectId       ProjectName     
 24               Beta           
 56               Alpha          
 57               Gamma          
 120              Aap
```

EXPECTED Result SET:

```
ProjectId      ProjectName         
______________________________
NULL           All                 
120            Aap                 
56             Alpha               
24             Beta                
57             Gamma
```

What I Need: I want to add a single row on top of the ordered result set of a query

Problems:

1. Subquerys are not allowed to have Order By clause
2. Doing Top 100 Percent destroys the order, and row having 'All' doesn't come at top
3. Declaring a Table variable inserting all entries in order and then performing union on this table 
   i.e.

   ```
    Select NULL as ProjectId, 'All' as ProjectName...
     UNION
    select * from @myTable
   ```

   again destroys the order

help me please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can order result of UNION, but you need to provide additional column to identify where the data came from - here it is SortOrder:

```
SELECT NULL as ProjectId, 'All' as ProjectName, 1 SortOrder
UNION ALL
SELECT  Project.ProjectId,  Project.ProjectName, 2 SortOrder
FROM Project
order by SortOrder, ProjectName
```

Note I replaced UNION with [UNION ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) as you do not need to DISTINCT result set.